# Add thumbnail to WordPress RSS with another tag

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed

I am using a Wordpress RSS to use in my iOS project. The feed doesn't have thumbnail links in it, so I searched and found this code to add thumbnail links to feed.

```
/* include thumbnail in RSS feed */
function add_thumb_to_RSS($content) {
   global $post;
   if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
      $content = '' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ) . '' . $content;
   }
   return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'add_thumb_to_RSS');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'add_thumb_to_RSS')
```

This code adds the image link in feed, but it adds as html code in the beginning of description tag like this:

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
<img width="150" height="150" src="http://www.ipadia.co/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/sayfada-bul-150x150.png" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="sayfada bul" title="sayfada bul" />Some text some text Some text some text Some text some text Some text some text Some text some text Some text some text ....
]]>
</description>
```

I want to add image link with another tag like `<image>` or `<thumb> the link </thumb>`. So I can parse this more easily.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it finally :) I changed the function that I posted before. The new function is this:

```
add_action('rss2_item', function(){
  global $post;

  $output = '';
  $thumbnail_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
  $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_ID, 'thumbnail');
  $output .= '<post-thumbnail>';
    $output .= '<url>'. $thumbnail[0] .'</url>';
    $output .= '<width>'. $thumbnail[1] .'</width>';
    $output .= '<height>'. $thumbnail[2] .'</height>';
    $output .= '</post-thumbnail>';

  echo $output;
});
```

This gives the image link in new tag `<post-thumbnail>` like I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 functions in wordpress that can help you in a very easy way, try this:

```
(int) $id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );
```

Edit:

To modify the feed you can check [this documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds)

One easy option is modifying directly the feed template, an example:

in file wp-includes/feed-rss2.php (note you may modify another feed template as "feed-rss.php", "feed-atom.php") you can add the new tag:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.get_option('blog_charset').'"?'.'>'; ?>

<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
    <?php do_action('rss2_ns'); ?>
>

<channel>
    <title><?php bloginfo_rss('name'); wp_title_rss(); ?></title>
    <atom:link href="<?php self_link(); ?>" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link><?php bloginfo_rss('url') ?></link>
    <description><?php bloginfo_rss("description") ?></description>
    <lastBuildDate><?php echo mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_lastpostmodified('GMT'), false); ?></lastBuildDate>
    <language><?php bloginfo_rss( 'language' ); ?></language>
    <sy:updatePeriod><?php echo apply_filters( 'rss_update_period', 'hourly' ); ?></sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency><?php echo apply_filters( 'rss_update_frequency', '1' ); ?></sy:updateFrequency>
    <?php do_action('rss2_head'); ?>
    <?php while( have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <item>
        <title><?php the_title_rss() ?></title>
        <link><?php the_permalink_rss() ?></link>
        <comments><?php comments_link_feed(); ?></comments>
        <pubDate><?php echo mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_post_time('Y-m-d H:i:s', true), false); ?></pubDate>
        <dc:creator><?php the_author() ?></dc:creator>
        <?php the_category_rss('rss2') ?>
        <?php 
            //start modified code to add tag with post thumb url
            (int) $id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
            $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $id ); 
        ?>
        <thumb><?php echo $thumb_url;?></thumb>
            <?php //end modified code to add tag with post thumb url ?>
        <guid isPermaLink="false"><?php the_guid(); ?></guid>
<?php if (get_option('rss_use_excerpt')) : ?>
        <description><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss() ?>]]></description>
<?php else : ?>
        <description><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss() ?>]]></description>
    <?php if ( strlen( $post->post_content ) > 0 ) : ?>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<?php the_content_feed('rss2') ?>]]></content:encoded>
    <?php else : ?>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss() ?>]]></content:encoded>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
        <wfw:commentRss><?php echo esc_url( get_post_comments_feed_link(null, 'rss2') ); ?></wfw:commentRss>
        <slash:comments><?php echo get_comments_number(); ?></slash:comments>
<?php rss_enclosure(); ?>
    <?php do_action('rss2_item'); ?>
    </item>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Thank you for your good answer, appreciate it. I solved it with a short method and I posted it as answer. Thank you again Mario.

Answer (score -1):

There is a plugin to do this for WordPress that adds the image as an enclosure.

https://github.com/kasparsd/feed-image-enclosure/blob/master/feed-image-enclosure.php